# How to access svn server installed on centos(putty) from svn client from windows os?

Tags: svn, centos

I have done follwing things

**1 Edit Hosts File**

$ sudo nano -w /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4

127.0.0.1 www.example.com myexample

192.168.1.150 www.example.com myexample

::1 localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6 ::1 myserver.myhome.com myserver

**2 Edit httpd.conf**

$ sudo nano -w /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

ServerName www.example.com

**3 Edit network**

$ sudo nano -w /etc/sysconfig/network HOSTNAME=www.example.com

when i tried to print hostname it is displaying www.example.com.

I have checkin the simple project through file:///var/www/svn/repos..it's working

But from client machine or accesing by foolowing is not working

1)from windows or command promt in centos

svn import /tmp/myprj/ http://"www.example.com"/var/www/svn/repos/mytest -m "initial repository"

or

svn import /tmp/myprj/ http://"ipaddressonly"/var/www/svn/repos/mytest -m "initial repository"

getting following message

svn: OPTIONS of 'http://"ipaddress"/var/www/svn/repos/mytest1': 200 OK (http://"ipaddress")

Comment: Have you tried this ? `http://www.example.com/svn/repos/mytest`

Comment: I tried that option also but same error 
svn: OPTIONS of 'http://"ipaddress"/svn/repos/mytest1': 200 OK (http://"ipaddress")